# Ошибка при вызове python скрипта из Runtime

Tags: java, python, linux, ubuntu

Необходимо по команде выполнить запуск python скрипта. Не использовал jython т.к. скрипт содержит библиотеку todoist-api. Запуск скрипта выполняется по команде:

```
try {
        String cmd = "/home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    }
    catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

на что получаю исключение -

```
" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py": error=13, Отказано в доступе"
```

Менял параметры доступа в том числе через chmod -r 777. 
OC Ubuntu 18.04 lts.

Comment: А что будет если: `String cmd = "python /home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py";` ?

Comment: 1) А кто пытается выполнить скрипт ? Тот же *kiryushin* или кто-то другой? Например - *cron*.

2) Надо проверить  права не только самого файла *stmtest1.py* но и всех каталогов по его пути.

3) А в файле *stmtest1.py* в первой строке шебанг есть ?

Comment: @AlexYu Странно, но это помогло, т.к. несколькими днями ранее пробовал запускать и через python, и через python3.6. Только скрипт не выполняется, но наверное это проблема уже с другим. На форумах везде видел упоминания что несколько параметров нужно передавать через String[] cmd = {" первое сообщение","второе сообщение "}. Надо сделать пример без сторонних библиотек, чтобы точно узнать запускается ли скрипт или нет. После этого, если поможет закрою обсуждение.

Comment: @СергейКирюшин ничего странного. Когда вы запускаете скрипт в терминале, оболочка читает [шебанг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)), получает из него путь к интерпретатору, запускает интерпретатор и передаёт ему файл скрипта. Рантайм JVM этого не делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По комментариям стало ясно, что проблема запуска - не найден интерпретатор python.

Одного `chmod +x [имя скрипта]` недостаточно, чтобы сделать файл исполняемым. Точнее сказать: **правильно исполняемым**.

## Варианты решения

### 1. `chmod +x`  и  "shebang"

По классике, надо добавить первой строкой в скрипте "shebang": `#!python` или `#!/usr/bin/python` или `#!//usr/bin/env python` или даже `#p!ipenv run`

Главноe - надо помнить, что окружение созданное `Runtime.getRuntime()` может отличаться от того, что может создаваться в `bash`/`zsh`/`fish`/etc и проверять `$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH` и прочее.

### 2. Указать интепретатор в `cmd` напрямую

Изменить команду запуска скрипта, не полагаясь на "shebang" и указать интерпретатор напрямую:

```
String cmd = "python /home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py";
```

Проверять опять же переменные окружения созданные Runtime.getRuntime.

Интерпретатор:

- для простых случаев - просто `python`
- для случаев сложнее - создать virtualenv и запускать с командой инициализации окружения. Моя рекомендация - использовать `pipenv` и запускать c `pipenv run [имя скрипта]`

Answer (score 1):

По незнанию, при создании проекта python забыл, что указал создание виртуальной среды и поэтому после запуска скрипта из Runtime не мог подцепить библиотеку todoist-api. Поэтому я:

1. Пересоздал проект без создания виртуальной среды (venv)
2. Указал в ручную интерпретатор и добавил shebang
3. С помощью pip3 добавил библиотеку todoist-api
4. В вызове скрипта указал:

   String cmd = "python3.6 /home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm2/stm.py";
           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: Смысл добавлять собственный ответ - только если все остальные ответы не удовлетворительны, а правильный найден самостоятельно. И тогда надо публиковать: и собственный ответ и его же и принимать как решение. Иначе - нелогично

Comment: @AlexYu Ответ выше более полный в нем есть решение с сохранением виртуальной среды. Свой вариант написал, как альтернативу, если что-то не получится